# Time dilation due to constantly accelerating drives

Tags: space-travel, hard-science, spaceships, time

I am writing a story on a civilization that has the ability to make constant accelerating drives.  The ships will accelerate with 8g's (heavy worlders) for half of the trip and then de-accelerate for the remaining half.  Thus the need for artificial gravity is no longer necessary.  I know however for large distances time dilation will become an issue and I don't know how to deal with it for an accelerating drive.

I recently found this app which calculates the time dilation due to constantly accelerating drives but I am not quite sure if I should trust it.

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.dahak.sci_fitraveler&hl=en

The calculation methods have a lot of sinh functions for the time dilation and I've only ever seen time dilation with square roots.  I can't get the book the app references so I was wondering if anyone here has worked with constant acceleration drives and knows of any good references on the time dilation which results?  If there are numerical examples which I can check against the app, I would appreciate that as well.

Comment: This sounds like a question better asked on [physics.se]. We are more focused on building fictional worlds than verifying that a particular app does it's time dilation calculations correctly.

Comment: Wikipedia has the derivation of the equations.  Note that it contains trig: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relativistic_rocket